# Wordpress (?) published older posts to facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, publish, posts

We have a big problem with wordpress(?)

We use a plugin (Social Media autopublish) to post our new articles automatically to facebook. (I use this plugin in another website works well there.)

So the problem is wordpress published some older (from 2014-15) (10-15) article to facebook today. Interestingly this happened last time a week ago 2x times a day.

**We didnt updated these posts or anything and the site is not hacked or anything...**

Maybe wp-cron is not good?

So where is the problem? and why?

Thank you!

Comment: you may need to contact the plugin author about it, or try to debug his code if it is not minified/obfuscated.